# Not able to turn on Bluetooth in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS hp laptop

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, laptop, hp

Bluetooth settings panel on my Ubuntu machine:

[image: Bluetooth turned off]

I tried to turn it on but it does not show

```
vanshaj@rockstar:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-21 23:10:48 IST; 18min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 649 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─649 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 21 23:13:39 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.1…rce
Sep 21 23:13:39 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.1…ink
Sep 21 23:20:33 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:20:37 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:21:00 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:21:40 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:22:26 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:24:26 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:24:30 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Sep 21 23:26:02 rockstar bluetoothd[649]: Failed to set mode: Blocked throug…12)
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I tried a couple of things including blocking and unblocking, restarting the Bluetooth and rebooting.

It started to work after reboot but then again the problem occurred. Now the icon on the list is also missing.

Comment: i also tried with blueman but problem remains, it instead prompted to turn Bluetooth on

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.